# Adding up instance variables of a class object

Tags: python

I want to sum up an instance variable of a class object in a list of that class object.

```
Class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 20

B = []
for i in range(10):
    B.append(A())

# Can this be made more pythonic?
sum = 0 
for i in B:
    sum += i.a
```

I was thinking along the lines of using a map function or something? Don't know if that's pushing it too much though. Just curious.

Comment: `sum(i.a for i in B)` (See: the tutorials on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).)

Comment: (As much as I dislike abusing the term "pythonic", I'd argue that list comprehensions are clearly more so than `map()` and `filter()`.)

Comment: @millimoose..This is actually giving me a TypeError saying 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @Nitin  That's probably because you still have `sum = 0` somewhere in your script.  This shows why it's bad to name your variables `sum`.

Comment: @Nitin The error is somewhere else than in my suggestion: http://ideone.com/Dx7v2I ([`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) is a builtin function in it, not your variable.)

Comment: @millimoose Yes got the error. sorry about that. List comprehensions are part of why I love python. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce`

```
reduce(lambda acc, c: acc + c, [i.a for i in B])
```

or `sum()` with comprehension

```
sum([i.a for i in B])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class A(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.a = 20

B = []
for i in range(10):
    B.append(A())

s = sum(i.a for i in B)

print s
```

works.